# How deactivate TTY and set GUI as default after booting Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: 16.04, command-line, tty

I can't log in with the usual login screen graphical user interface, every time I restart the OS I am taken back again to the tty terminal interface to log in.

Tried `sudo init 5` but bootscreen appears for some seconds and quickly disappears.

When I run `startx`:

```
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
xauth: error in locking authority file /home/pmutua/.Xauthority
```

Comment: `xauth: error in locking authority file /home/pmutua/.Xauthority`

Comment: Tried the approach a while ago got `could not open file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial.......` `(30: Read-only file system) `

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in the logs there was `(30: Read-only file system)` meaning that my HDD partition at `dev/sda6` was in `ro`  read-only mode so literally even if I tried to `sudo apt-get install` anything that would fail.

#### Solution

I had to remount the `dev/sda6` to `rw` read and write:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda6
```

Then, I run `startx` in the terminal which activated the GUI and I could finally see the log in screen.